# Помогите с кнопкой в Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть такая кнопка:
[image: Кнопка]

Она должна открывать группу в вк

Сам скрипт взят с сайта юнити

```
void Start() {
    Application.OpenURL("http://vk.com/");
}
```

А что вводить в обработчик нажатий,т.е сюда
[image: Обработчик]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо корректно воспользоваться механизмом `UnityEvents`.

Для этого, создайте скрипт, который унаследован от `MonoBehaviour` и добавьте к нему метод допустим `Open(string url)`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenLink : MonoBehaviour {

    public void Open(string url) {
         Application.OpenURL(url);
    }

}
```

Затем добавьте этот скрипт на пустой GameObject под названием OpenLink.

В скрипте кнопки сошлитесь на объект OpenLink в списке обработчиков и выбирайте метод `Open`, а в поле, в которое Вы написали "что сюда писать?", впишите `url`, который необходимо открыть.

---

Я сделал следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и по клику на кнопку открылся браузер.